# how to get a number to add like 12 is 3

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

i cant get the code right to ask for a number like 12 and then say the sum of the number is 3 in java netbeans

i got this so far

```
public class Exercise2_6 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner( System.in );

       System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 and 1000");
       // Enter a number between 0 and 1000

       Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );      
       int x = in.nextInt( );

       System.out.println(" The sum of the digits is "n" ");
       System.out.println("n" = (in.nextInt( ) /100));  //this give you first digit
       System.out.println("n" = in.nextInt( )%100); //this gives a number representing the remaining two digits


    }

}
```

and it gives me back

```
run:
Enter a number between 0 and 1000
12
 The sum of the digits is 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - not a statement
    at Exercise2_6.main(Exercise2_6.java:55)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Comment: Instead of `"n" = ` you should write `"n= " +`

Comment: Try this!
System.out.println(" The sum of the digits is n");
    System.out.println("n="+  (in.nextInt( ) /100));  //this give you first digit
    System.out.println("n="+in.nextInt( )%100);

Answer (score 1):

Strings must be concatenated using the + operator.
Therefore, your statement of `"n" = ....` is not correct.
Replace

```
System.out.println("n" = (in.nextInt( ) /100));  //this give you first digit
System.out.println("n" = in.nextInt( )%100); //this gives a number representing the remaining two digits
```

with

```
System.out.println("n = " + in.nextInt()/100);
System.out.println("n = " + in.nextInt()%100);
```

However, the above statements will refer to TWO different ints, one for each time nextInt() is called. I don't know the purpose of your code but you should get into the practice of storing variables incase you need to use them again.

If you stored each int locally, for example

```
int n = in.nextInt();
```

you could then refer to it again later, for example by appending the above statements to

```
System.out.println("n = " + n/100); ....
```

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not be the most efficient or 'correct' way of doing it, but I'm a complete noob myself. So, this is how I managed it. By using a while loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfDigits {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    int i, a = 0, x = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 and 1000: ");

    i = input.nextInt();

    while(i != 0) {
        a = i % 10;
        i = i / 10;
        x = x + a;
    }

    System.out.println("The sum of the digits in your number is: " + x);

}
```

}

Comment: Yep I'm pretty sure this is the nicest way to do this (though ´a ´  isn't strictly necessary).   Note that this is valid in the general case and OP only wanted up to 1000. Much cleaner this way though.